# homebrew Formula to install package

Tags: homebrew

As part of new joinees, we provide the FAQ for running internal homebrew formula, that installs from zip/tar.gz files, we install using " brew tap ..." . However, we are separately running "brew install mariadb@10.2" as well as running "brew tap...". Question -  wanted to consolidate all brew commands into one using formula, i.e i wanted to have ability to install for this package name  "mariadb@10.2" into TAP formula we have.

Please share the information if any.

Let me know if not clear.

Comment: Two questions: 1- Is your tap a GitHub repository that you tap using `brew tap org/repo`; 2- do you install _only_ `mariadb@10.2` or do you install some formulas from your tap as well?

Comment: @bfontaine : Yes our tap is based on github repository (for example, we used to run "brew tap https://github.com/org/firststimessetup". So in this TAP, we want to include "mariadb@10.2" rather than running multiple brew commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `brew install mariadb@10.2 && brew tap ...`, but you can’t combine `brew install mariadb@10.2` *and* `brew tap ...` into one `brew` command.

However, running `brew install` on a formula from a tap you don’t have automatically `tap`s the latter:

```
brew install org/tap/thing
```

Is equivalent to:

```
brew tap org/tap
brew install org/tap/thing
```

Where `org/tap` is the GitHub repository `https://github.com/org/homebrew-tap`.

This means that if you want to install `mariadb@10.2` as well as some other formula from that tap, you can run a command like this:

```
brew install mariadb@10.2 org/firsttimesetup/xyz
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
brew tap org/firsttimesetup
brew install mariadb@10.2 org/firsttimesetup/xyz
```

Comment: Got you @bfontaine, what i am saying is, we have "Brewfile" in the tag org/tap git repo. I wanted to include mariadb@10.2 in the brewfile, should i mention in Brewfile :                                                                 "brew 'mariadb@10.2'"

Comment: @harekrshn you should have mentioned it in your question. A tap and a repo with a Brewfile are two different things. To answer your question: yes, you should add `brew "mariadb@10.2"`.

Comment: Instead of "Where `org/tap` is the GitHub repository `https://github.com/org/tap`." I think you mean "Where `org/tap` is the GitHub repository `https://github.com/org/homebrew-tap`."?